# Prove Prop 4.11

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

> **4.11 Proposition.** Let $X$ be a set and let $\mathcal{S}$ be any collection of subsets of $X$ such that $X=\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal{S}}V$. Let $\mathcal{T}$ denote the collection of all subsets of $X$ that can be obtained using two operations:
>
> 1. taking finite intersections of sets in $\mathcal{S}$;
> 2. taking arbitrary unions of sets obtained in 1. Then $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $X$.
>
> *Proof*. Exercise. $\qquad\square$

The following Proposition comes off [www.mth527.site](http://www.mth527.site) I will take my best shot at it.

**My understanding**

By taking union of empty sets $\cup\emptyset=\emptyset\in\tau$

Let {$C_j:j\in J$} be family members of $\tau$ Then each $C_j$ is a union of the members of S Hence the union of all
{$C_j:j\in J$} is also union of all the members in S and so in
$\tau$

We want to verify  $Y\cap Z\in\tau$ (1)

Let Y,Z$\in\tau$

But $Y=\bigcup_{V\cap S}V$ then for $V\in S$
and V$\in\tau $ and $Z=\bigcup_{W\in S}W$
then we have $W\in S$ for $W\in\tau$

$$Y\cap Z=\bigcup_{V\in S}V)\bigcap(\bigcup_{W\in S}W)= \bigcup_{V\in S}(\bigcup_{W \in S}(V\cap W)$$

So $Y\cap Z\in\tau$

We want to verify (2)

So if $T\subset X$ and $S\subset X$ then $S\subset T$ since arbitrary unions are taken
from it So if $V\in S$ so that $V\in\tau$, $\bigcup(Y\cap Z)=\bigcup_{V\in S}\bigcup_{W,V\in S}(V\cap W)$

[theorem source](https://www.mth527.site/assets/notes/mth427_notes_4.pdf)

Comment: Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your answer; but it looks to me like you are trying to verify (1) and (2) that are given in the problem statement; when really your $Y$, $Z$ must come from $\mathscr{T}$ and the goal is to show $\mathscr{T}$ satisfies all the axioms for a topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The family $\mathcal{S}$ is called a sub-base of the topology $\mathcal{T}$.
In the following, we will prove that $\mathcal{T}$ is indeed a topology,
known as the topology generated by $\mathcal{S}$.

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the collection of all finite intersections of
sets in $\mathcal{S}.$ Such collection $\mathcal{B}$ is known as
the base generated by $\mathcal{S}$.

Note that $\mathcal{B}$ is stable under taking finite intersection.
For, let $A,B\in\mathcal{B}$, then $A=\cap_{i=1}^{m}A_{i}$ and $B=\cap_{j=1}^{n}B_{j}$
for some $A_{i},B_{j}\in\mathcal{S}$. Note that $A\cap B=\cap\left(\{A_{i}\mid1\leq i\leq m\}]\cup\{B_{j}\mid1\leq j\leq n\}\right),$
which is a finite intersection of sets in $\mathcal{S}$, so $A\cap B\in\mathcal{B}$.
Also note that $\mathcal{S}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ and by considering
intersection of the empty family, we have $X=\cap\emptyset\in\mathcal{B}$.

Lastly, we verify that $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology:

1. Clearly $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{T}$. In particular, $X\in\mathcal{T}$.
2. By taking union of the empty family, we have that $\emptyset=\cup\emptyset\in\mathcal{T}$.
3. Let $\{A_{i}\mid i\in I\}\subseteq\mathcal{T}$ be an arbitrary
   family of sets in $\mathcal{T}$. For each $i\in I$, there exists a family
   $\mathcal{C}_{i}$ of sets in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $A_{i}=\cup\mathcal{C}_{i}$.
   Let $\mathcal{C}=\cup_{i\in I}\mathcal{C}_{i}$ which is a family
   of sets in $\mathcal{B}$. Now, $\cup_{i\in I}A_{i}=\cup\mathcal{C},$
   which is a union of sets in $\mathcal{B}$, and hence $\cup_{i\in I}A_{i}\in\mathcal{T}$.
   That is, $\mathcal{T}$ is stable under taking arbitrary union.
4. Let $A,B\in\mathcal{T}$. There exist families $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}$ of
   sets in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $A=\cup\mathcal{C}$ and $B=\cup\mathcal{D}$.
   Denote $\mathcal{C=}\{A_{i}\mid i\in I\}$ and $\mathcal{D}=\{B_{j}\mid j\in J\}$,
   where $I,J$ are index sets. Then
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   A\cap B & = & \left(\cup_{i\in I}A_{i}\right)\cap B\\
    & = & \cup_{i\in I}\left(A_{i}\cap B\right)\\
    & = & \cup_{i\in I}\left(A_{i}\cap\left(\cup_{j\in J}B_{j}\right)\right)\\
    & = & \cup_{i\in I}\left(\cup_{j\in J}(A_{i}\cap B_{j})\right).
   \end{eqnarray*}
   Let $\mathcal{E}=\{A_{i}\cap B_{j}\mid i\in I\mbox{ and }j\in j\}$,
   which is a family of sets in $\mathcal{B}$ (recall that $\mathcal{B}$
   is stable under taking finite intersection, so $A_{i},B_{j}\in\mathcal{B}\Rightarrow A_{i}\cap B_{i}\in\mathcal{B}$).
   The above shows that $A\cap B=\cup\mathcal{E}$, a union of sets in
   $\mathcal{B}$, so $A\cap B\in\mathcal{T}.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

(1) Can you show that $\varnothing$ and $X$ are both in $\mathscr{T}$? To show the latter, be sure to use the fact that $X = \bigcup_{V \in S} V$.

(2) Can you show that finite intersections of subsets of $\mathscr{T}$ are also in $\mathscr{T}$ ? For this, you might want to remember that "finite intersection of (finite intersections of sets from $S$)" is still a finite intersection of sets from $S$.

(3) Likewise in (2), can you show arbitrary unions of objects of $\mathscr{T}$ is also in $\mathscr{T}$?

**Edit:** You will have likely have to fill in some details in (2) because the sets in $\mathscr{T}$ are also arbitrary unions of finite intersections of sets from $S$; but that shouldn't be too hard to handle once you symbolically write things down

Comment: I guess l did not read the def of X. It is a subbase. It changes it So what did l say.